# OIM 12c Rest api to enable/disable user

Tags: oim

I am developing a web service to create and update users in OIM. The OIM 12c Rest api's are being used for this purpose. I am able to update the fields like first name, last name using the Update User api - /iam/governance/selfservice/api/v1/users/{uuid}.

I have to add the enable/disable user functionality in my service. I am not able to achieve this using the above rest service. Is there any other Rest api in OIM to set the usr_disabled flag?

Setup:
OIM url - http://:/iam/governance/selfservice/api/v1/users/1011

JSON Request:
{
    "requestId": "1234",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "usr_disabled",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "First Name",
            "value": "Peter"
        },
        {
            "name": "Last Name",
            "value": "Pan"
        }
    ]
}

JSON response from OIM:

{
    "title": "IAM-2050033 : ModifyUserDataset request cannot set or change attribute usr_disabled, since it is not defined in the corresponding data set.",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "IAM-2050033 : ModifyUserDataset request cannot set or change attribute usr_disabled, since it is not defined in the corresponding data set.",
    "instance": "oracle.iam.request.exception.RequestServiceException",
    "errorCode": "IAM-2050033",
    "referer": "http://cloud.kapstonellc.com:14011/iam/governance/selfservice/api/v1/users/1011"
}

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it helped you and correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in OIM and you need to use the workaround as of now. The workaround is as follows:

> To Disable User:

1. Set the user's `End Date` value
2. Set System property `XL.UserDeleteDelayPeriod` to `3600` (10 years)
3. Run Schedule Job `Disable/Delete User After End Date`

> To Enable User:

1. Set `Start Date` to some past date
2. Run Scheduled Job `Enable user After Start Date`